# Asio SSL error "handshake: no protocols available"

Tags: c++, asio

I'm trying to connect to gmail through SSL using Asio (stand alone version).

When I call `handshake`I get this error:

```
handshake: no protocols available
```

Here is the code:

```
asio::ssl::context sslContext(asio::ssl::context::sslv3);
sslContext.set_default_verify_paths();
asio::io_context ioc;
typedef asio::ip::tcp::socket Socket;
asio::ssl::stream<Socket> socket(ioc, sslContext)
auto endpointIt = resolver.resolve("smtp.gmail.com", to_string(465));
asio::connect(socket.lowest_layer(), endpointIt);
socket.lowest_layer().set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));
socket.set_verify_mode(asio::ssl::verify_peer);
socket.set_verify_callback(asio::ssl::rfc2818_verification(serverUrl));
try{
    socket.handshake(SslSocket::client);
}
catch(const std::exception& e){
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work around it replacing:

```
sslContext.set_default_verify_paths();
```

by:

```
sslContext.add_verify_path("/etc/ssl/certs");
```

That won't be portable but at least it's working now.